# Ember.js jump to/select item in list/table by value

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

Currently learning Ember.js by doing.
Using [Ember App Kit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit).

I have the basic relationship - a model "Order", that has many "Item".
I display order and items with following .hbs.

```
// templates/order.hbs
Order:{{info}}
Items:
{{#each items itemController="item"}}
  {{#if isEditing}}
    {{sku}}:
    {{input value=quantity focus-out='acceptChanges'}}
  {{else}}
    {{sku}}:
    <p {{action 'editItem' on='doubleClick'}}>
    {{quantity}}
    </p>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
{{input type="text" value=search action='query'}}
```

The controller merely handles those two actions.

```
// controllers/item.js
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: DS.attr('boolean'),
    actions: {
        editItem: function () {
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },
        acceptChanges: function () {
            this.set('isEditing', false);
            this.get('model').save();
        }
    }
});
```

And the simple model.

```
// models/item.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  order: DS.belongsTo('order', {async: true}),
  sku: DS.attr('string'),
  quantity: DS.attr('number'),
});
```

Order controller to handle query action from order.hbs.

```
// controllers/order.js
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    query: function() {
      var q = this.get('search');
      Ember.Logger.log(q); // this prints value to console
      // TODO: somehow search for the item and set isEditing on it
    }
  }
}
```

All this works fine.

I would like to add following feature:
An input field in order.hbs, where one could enter SKU and it would open (inline, like one had used double click) the corresponding item for editing.
How and where (in which controller or view) to do this?

My current understanding of ember.js suggests it has something to do with ArrayControllers or views. But I haven't found anything similar implemented.

**UPDATE:**
Moved isEditing from model to controller, more appropriate place for it.
Changed the example from "posts and comments" to "orders and items".

**UPDATE2:**
I have added the input field 'search', I can retrieve its value in order controller. However I do not believe this is the place to handle item search, is it?

Answer (score 0):

I changed design to achieve what I needed.

However this does not use `each` on order `hasMany` items anymore.
Instead there is items resource for each order and `/order/:id` redirects to `/order/:id/items`, so UX does not change.

```
// router.js
var Router = Ember.Router.extend();     
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('component-test');
  this.route('helper-test');
    this.resource('orders', function() {
        this.resource('order', {path: ':id'}, function() {
            this.resource('items');
        });
    });
});    
export default Router;

// routes/order.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('order', params.id);
    },
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('items');
    }
});

// routes/items.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var order = this.modelFor('order');
        return order.get('items');
    }
});

// templates/order.hbs
Order: {{info}}
{{outlet}}

// templates/items.hbs
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>SKU</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    {{#each}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{sku}}</td>
        {{#if isEditing}}
        <td>
              {{input value=quantity insert-newline='acceptChanges'}}
        </td>
        {{else}}
        <td {{action 'editItem' on='doubleClick'}}>
        {{quantity}}
        </td>
        {{/if}}
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
{{input type="text" value=searchItem action='query'}}

// controllers/items.js
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: "item",
    actions: {
        query: function() {
            var si = this.get('searchItem');
            var x = this.findBy('sku', si);
            if (x) {
                x.set('isEditing', true);
                this.set('searchItem', '');
            }
        }
    },
});

// controllers/item.js
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,
    actions: {
        editItem: function () {
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },
        acceptChanges: function () {
            this.set('isEditing', false);
            this.get('model').save();
        }
    }
});
```